# Can I say "What image do you have about my country?"

Tags: prepositions, expressions, american-english

I want to ask someone what they heard about my country; whether it's positive things or negative things.

Can I say "What image do you have about my country?"

Comment: Are you asking about someone's opinion about your country? There are several ways of saying this, and yours is pretty good.

Comment: You would not be misunderstood if you asked “What image do you have about (anything)?” but you would also not be strictly correct.

An "image" is like a photograph or any other picture… it's always "of" and never "about" the subject.

An image, photograph or any other picture might well say/have something to say about the subject but that is a different part of any language.

the image itself is always "of…" the subject.

Answer (score 15):

To me the word "image" sounds unusual here, especially coupled with "about".

I think a more common way to ask this question would be "What impression do you have about my country?"

The meaning here of "impression" is

> an idea, feeling, or opinion about something or someone, especially one formed without conscious thought or on the basis of little evidence. (Oxford Languages)

Comment: Or more simply "What do you think of my country?"  "Image" is more commonly used when talking about a third party's (often a collective noun) perception.

Comment: I think "What impression do you have of my country?" sounds way more natural (is "about" even correct?)

Answer (score 14):

We have an image (a mental picture) *of* something, not *about* it.

A chart from [Google Ngram](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=image%20of%2C%20image%20about&year_start=1800&year_end=2019&corpus=26&smoothing=3&direct_url=t1%3B%2Cimage%20of%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Cimage%20about%3B%2Cc0) comparing the instances of *image of* (blue line), and *image about* (red line)
[image]

Comment: Agree, but think ngrams is a unsuited for this.

Comment: @Lambie - Why? Many others have used it here to prove that a particular version of a phrase is the usual one.

Comment: Mainly, because these types of questions are about spoken language and NGRAMS tracks written language. Anyway, one can imagine saying that an image can be about something, as opposed to of something. Those are different meanings, right? The OP is looking for "of" here.

Comment: The problem with ngrams here is that we are looking specifically for "image of/about my country" (a metaphorical sense of image) and the ngrams graph will pick up lots of "image of a scene in a lens, or the image of the triangle after reflection in the line.  Which are different senses of "image"

Comment: Even worse, ngrams will pick up the words "image of" in contexts where they're not even in the same sentence. Ngrams is a useful tool, but it's important to be aware of its limitations.

Comment: If someone asked me "What image do you have of my country?" then I would guess that they're asking me what kinds of photographs of their country I have.

Comment: @Tanner Why? They're not asking what _images_ you have. Look at [this article](https://aleteia.org/2017/12/19/pope-is-asked-what-image-do-you-have-of-yourself-his-answer-is-worthy-of-reflection/). The Pope asked "What image do you have of yourself?" - Upon hearing this, would you pull out your phone and show him your latest selfies?

Comment: @Llama Non-native speakers occasionally use a singular word where a plural word would be more appropriate, and to me, "image of yourself" sounds more like it probably refers to an overall perception whereas "image of my country" sounds more like it's probably an awkward way of referring to a photograph.

Answer (score 6):

It sounds perfectly okay to me. It may well be the sort of construction I would use myself, as a native English speaker.

Comment: Maybe the OP is nostalgic and would like to see some photos...? How can we be sure? Highly unlikely, I know but I think an answer like this is really appropriate as a comment but without even citing the sentence it's pretty bare.

Comment: Don't we usually have an image _of_ something, not _about_ something? I think _impression_ would also be much more idiomatic (what's your impression of X?) unless the asker is really interested in a _mental image_ (imagined visual reality).

Comment: @TypeIA Of, about, whatever. IMO they're both good. You can say this in many different ways. The question being asked was that if the given construct was correct or not. If you genuinely believe it is *not* correct, then write it as an answer and mark mine down.

Comment: @Mari-LouA Sorry, I'm new here. Is there an accepted minimum size limit for an answer?

Comment: [I'm quite sure](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=image+of%2Cimage+about&year_start=1800&year_end=2019&corpus=26&smoothing=3&direct_url=t1%3B%2Cimage%20of%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Cimage%20about%3B%2Cc0) "image about" is not idiomatic. It's "image of" as im Kate Bunting's answer. -1.

Comment: @TypeIA Maybe my (native) English usage is unconventional, then. In future I'll wind my neck in.

Comment: @TypeIA image about **can be** idiomatic. "The judges felt the images were about the devastation of poverty and therefore we in line with the contest's rules." Images, books, paintings, stories, etc. can always be "about" something. But the OP is not looking for that here.

Comment: @Lambie Yes, agreed.

Comment: @TypeIA: I disagree with the so-called 'Google NGram' that you linked and your  '-1'; Google NGram gets the information from books published in English not what people say on a day to day basis, they can't outdo native speakers.

Comment: @Void It's also based on 4 decades of listening to native speakers (I am one). Please cite some evidence that native speakers say "images about" in this context, and I will retract my vote.

Comment: @Void That is a reasonable point, but the problem is that in this case the answer is wrong *even for* spoken usage among natives. For this particular meaning of the word "image" we are referring to a *mental* image (as opposed to e.g. a photo). Such images are images *of* some other thing. They are not *about* topics in the sense of "the judges felt the images were about the devastation..." in the comment above.

Answer (score 6):

The corpus from [english-corpora.org/coca/](https://english-corpora.org/coca/) contains a few instances of "image about".

Sadly the website really dislikes hotlinking, so any users who would like to personally repeat the results I have found will need to perform a (free) registration and enter the query themselves.

But here are a few examples:

- This greatly affirmed their own **image about** their capabilities and potential to be college successes.
- I just want to tell that story to the world, so we can change this monolithic **image about**' Black America' and the inner city.
- On another page it continued with a grisly **image about** the meaning of TIT's work, " to transform the inside of a murky coffin into a carousel of the decapitated. "
- I agree with Zach that if I'm not confronting other people with their behaviour (for example colleagues talking me down, stepping on my toes to show how well they do) they are forming a mental **image about** me that is incorrect and allows them to continue that behaviour.
- You've got to present a crisp, clear and compelling -- as well as authentic -- **image about** who you are, which is what we now call your personal brand.
- This greatly affirmed their own **image about** their capabilities and potential to be college successes.
- I believe that the truth about the Kosovo and Metochia problem and situation should finally start to be known in this country because your people has been manipulated for months and years and has been given one very false **image about** our policy, our objectives and the policy and objectives of Albanian separatists and terrorists.
- In fact, a military's involvement in politics can involve a whole continuum, from minimal to maximal influence, depending on the ability of the civilian political leadership to hold on to power, the state of internal and external threats, and the officer corps' **image about** its role and place in society.

Comment: Did you do a similar search for 'image of' and compare frequencies?